# How do I create resizable objects in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js, webgl

Lets say I have a simple cube and some variables specifying its width, height and depth.

How do I update my THREE mesh when the w/h/d changes? (I have everything else like changelisteners etc). Do I update vertices directly? Or is it easier to just redraw everything?

Comment: How about using the object's scale vector ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think easiest would be to create your cube with 1 unit dimensions (1x1x1). Then set the dimensions by scaling it:

```
mesh.scale.x = width;
mesh.scale.y = height;
mesh.scale.z = depth;
```

Not actually sure if mesh supports scale, if not, you can wrap it in Object3D

```
var obj = new THREE.Object3D();
    obj.add(mesh);
obj.scale.x = width;
obj.scale.y = height;
obj.scale.z = depth;
```

Nothing stops you from modifying the vertices directly. I think you need to specify `geometry.dynamic=true;` and then `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;` in that case.